# Создание функций в объекте

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  sayHi() {
    // ...
  },
  sayBye: function() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Есть ли разница в объявлении функций sayHi() и satBye() ?

Answer (score 2):

Кратко могу ответить так:
Эти два варианта имеют небольшие отличия, связанные с наследованием объектов. (Подтверждение моих слов можно найти здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods).

Конкретно для вашего случая, в чем заключаются отличия, я так и не нашел. Но могу объяснить в чем отличия для следующего способа написания:

```
class Msg {
    constructor() {
        this.sayHi = function() {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    }

    sayBye() {
        console.log("by");
    }
}
```

Метод будет записан в prototype. Это можно проверить с помощью следующего кода:

```
console.log(Msg.prototype.sayBy);
```

А вот sayHi будет присвоен объекту только в момент вызова new Msg();

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант это новый синтаксис ES6. Так что разница может быть в совместимости с старыми браузерами